# Limite de linha no RecycleView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, android-adapter

Tenho um `RecycleView` que retorna muitas linha, configuro o `layout_height` para um tamanho específico, mais de um celular para outro a quantidade de linha aumenta ou diminui, gostaria de ajustar para que apareça uma quantidade de linhas.

ex: 4 linhas, se quiser mostrar mais tem a barra de rolagem.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece devido aos diferentes tamanhos e densidades de tela do sistema.

Em termos de usabilidade, se você tem um número pequeno e fixo de linhas (como no caso de um menu) podes utilizar algo como o LinearLayout ou ConstraintLayout e configurá-lo de modo a utilizar todo o tamanho disponível, então distribuir o tamanho dos itens de maneira proporcional para preencher a tela.

Se a lista precisa ser dinâmica (justificando a utilização do RecyclerView) e o tamanho do seu *dataset* variar, talvez seja melhor não se preocupar com o fato dos itens "preencherem perfeitamente a tela" - até mesmo porquê após a rolagem os itens do topo e base ficarão parcialmente visíveis. Caso a exibição integral dos itens seja um requisito, uma boa solução pode ser utilizar bibliotecas como [esta](https://github.com/Dan-TD/SnappyRecyclerView), que irá ancorar o scroll dos elementos.

Caso as sugestões anteriores não resolvam o problema, você pode calcular dinamicamente a altura dos itens do layout de acordo com o tamanho da tela. Para isso é necessário obter a altura visível do RecyclerView, subtrair margens e acolchoamento (*padding*) e dividir pela quantidade de itens a serem exibidos. O resultado será a altura de cada item, que pode ser definida no método `onBindViewHolder` do seu adapter.

Uma solução mais simples seria definir a altura dos itens de acordo com as dimensões da tela. A [documentação do Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) explica como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

no seu `getItemCount` tente usar `return Math.min(items.size(), 4);`

Comment: Eduardo não resolveu até piorou, pois o `RecycleView` ficou fixo com 4 itens sem a barra de rolagem.